# What are the pros and cons of using HttpUriRequest vs. HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, performance, httprequest, droidquery

I have made several apps and libraries for `Android` that use [HttpUriRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest.html) to create network requests (for example, my [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery) library), however I have been seeing some new libraries emerging (such as [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), which is meant to be extraordinarily fast) that use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead.

Does `HttpURLConnection` provide a faster connection than `HttpUriRequest`, or are these two classes basically equivalent? What are the pros and cons to using one over the other?

Comment: Google prefers people to use the HttpURLConnection. They are not going to continue to update the apache httpclient library. Here is a [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered on the [Android Dev Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html):

### Which client is best?

> Apache HTTP client has fewer bugs on Eclair and
>   Froyo. It is the best choice for these releases.
>
> For Gingerbread and better, HttpURLConnection is the best choice. Its
>   simple API and small size makes it great fit for Android. Transparent
>   compression and response caching reduce network use, improve speed and
>   save battery. New applications should use HttpURLConnection; it is
>   where we will be spending our energy going forward.